# UnParseable Date Exception :"2015-02-06T16:05:20"

Tags: java, datetime

I have a Date Variable "StartTime", in which i need to store this input String "2015-02-06T16:05:20"

I tried like below, but it gives Unparsable Date Exception. What i am doing wrong?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String inputTime = "2015-02-06T16:05:20";
setStartTime(dateFormat.parse(inputTime));
```

Comment: There is a `T` in your input between the date and the time, while it is not there in the format.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the requirement, it have to be there.

Comment: That looks like ISO8601 without zone suffix, any chance you could change underlying format, you could then use Java 8 built in methods to parse for free..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change you date format to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`

Read more `Java` [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I tried like that but it gives the following error, ERROR [2015-03-09 12:33:28] [] [http-9999-1] - [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-02-06%27T%2716:05:20"

Comment: @Rajkishan please use correct format and matching String date. else your try will fail.